# Average power of a signal

Tags: signal-processing, systems-of-equations

What is the average power of the signal below?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signal is $f(t)$, and the period of the function is $T$, then compute
$$ \frac1T \int_0^T |f(t)|^2 \, dt .$$
In your case, it should be very easy to compute the integral.

Comment: But how to find f(t)?

Comment: Well $f(t) = 10 (t-0.05)$ for $0 \le t \le 0.1$.  That is, use the point slope formula on each line segment.